# Desactivar numeros de teclado en android studio para que solo permita introducir 0 y 1

Tags: java, android-studio, xml

En esta ocasión estoy en un dilema , estoy creando una aplicación que transforme una oración o palabra dada a su equivalente en exadecimal, esto con el propósito de generar una trama bsc e imprimirla para que el usuario pueda visualizarla, pero al avanzar en el proyecto me tope con el problema de que en android studio puedo utilizar el teclado en tipo numérico, pero me sigue aceptando números distintos a el 1 y 0 , necesito que solo se pueda introducir 1 y 0 esto con la finalidad de poder introducir la cabecera, detección de errores y las demás partes que conforman la trama bsc todo debe ser en binario, y no se como desactivar los números en el teclado distintos a 1 y 0 , si alguien me podría dar una solución , utilizar alguna condición un try catch o alguna manera de desactivar los números se los agradecería.

Dejo el enlace a GitHub de mi proyecto en android studio para quien guste ayudarme.

https://github.com/AntiDesert5/Tramas.git

gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacer lo que quieres lo mas sencillo es hacerte un metodo validador, al que le pasarias por parametro el id de la vista, si no pasa el validador que saque un mensaje con el tipo de error.

```
private boolean isValid(Int id) {
        EditText valorView = (EditText)findViewById(id);
        String valorString = valorView.getText().toString().trim();
        if(valorString.isEmpty()){
           showSnackBar(valorView,"Por favor ingrese un valor")
        }
        switch (id){
          case R.id.IngValor:
               //pon tu validacion solo para este TextView aqui
               if(condicionValida){
                 showSnackBar(valorView,"Valor valido");
               } else {
                 return false;
               }
               break;
          case R.id.MostValor:
               //pon tu validacion solo para este TextView aqui
               //Para comprobar que solo se han introducido 0 y 1:
               for(int j= 0;j<valorString.length();j++){
                    if(Character.isDigit(cade.charAt(j))){
                        if(!Character.valueOf(valorString.charAt(j)).equals('0') || !Character.valueOf(valorString.charAt(j)).equals('1')){
                            showSnackBar(valorView,"Por favor introduzca solo ceros y unos");
                            return false;
                        }
                    } else {
                        showSnackBar(valorView,"Por favor introduzca solo ceros y unos");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
               break;
          case R.id.MostValor2:
               //pon tu validacion solo para este TextView aqui
               break;
          case R.id.MostValor3:
               //pon tu validacion solo para este TextView aqui
               break;
          //Puedes validar mas vistas......
        }
        return true;
    }

private void showSnackBar(View v, String message) {
    Snackbar.make(v, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```